# Setting a max axis value or range step for a Morris Bar Chart?

Tags: morris.js

I was wondering if it is possible to set a max axis value (say, I want the highest point of my data to be the top end of the y-axis) on a bar chart? I see there are options for ymin and ymax on line charts but I can't seem to find any information about the bar charts.

Also, it would be helpful if anyone knew how to force the range between axis lanes to be a certain amount (say step up by 250 each line instead of the generated amount which in my case is too high for my liking).

Answer (score 12):

- **Set a maximum value for the `y` axis**

You can, indeed, set the `ymax` for bar charts also (even though this is not documented).

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ymax: 300, // set this value according to your liking
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

And have your `y` axis set to this maximum value:

[image]

- **Set a range value for the `y` axis**

It seems that it's not possible to set a range value for the `y` axis. This value appears to be computed according to the values of the data passed to `Morris.Bar`.

Answer (score 11):

Not documented, but you can set maximum y by applying ymax. You can manipulate the range by setting numLines (also not documented).

E.g.

```
var chart = new Morris.Bar({
...
    ymin: 0,
    ymax: 7,
    numLines: 8,
...
});
```

The above defined chart will display values from 0 to 7 and display a grid line for each integer between 0 and 7 (therefore 8 as a parameter)

Answer (score 1):

**I want the highest point of my data to be the top end of the y-axis**

The documentation is very sparse and confusing but this is possible using the `ymin` variable which is only documented in the [Lines & Area Charts](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html). The default value for that variable seems to be `auto 0` and changing it to just `auto` seems to produce the desired result as you can see below.

[image: ymin:auto]

**how to force the range between axis lanes to be a certain amount**

This does not seem to be possible, natively. However, you can kind of hack the axis label with the following function. It will round the value to multiples of 250 **BUT** the grid lines won't be at the number shown. E.g. say a grid line is at 570. The function below will change the label to 500 but the line will still show at 570 mark.

```
yLabelFormat: function(d) {
    return Math.round(d) - (Math.round(d) % 250);
},
```

As others have mentioned, you can set `ymax` to a value that you want your upper bound to be but since you want the highest data point to be the upper bound, set `ymax` to `auto`. You can also try changing `numLines` to different values for a better aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

To change to ymax call this

```
chart.options["ymax"] = 300;
```

Where chart is your chart variable